# How to use useState properly in this example?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, state

I have the following code:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
        name: '',
        surname: '',
        email: '',
        password: ''   
    });
```

However, I need to have something like:

```
 const [name, setName] = useState('');
 const [surname, setSurname] = useState('');
 const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
 const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
```

but still keeping the `setData()` function, as it is used.

Comment: @DavinTryon it's not true. if you pass an object with just name property it will override full data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, what you're looking for is a solution like the following:

```js
function MyComponent(props) {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({
    name: '',
    surname: ''
  })

  // will use `useEffect` as an example with an API call
  React.useEffect(() => {
    SomeAPICall()
      .then((data) => {
        setData({ 
          ...data, 
          name: data.name
        })
      })
  })
}
```

When calling `setState`, you need to copy the current state and update the property/properties that you want.

---

Alternatively, you could use `React.useReducer` to accomplish the same thing:

```js
function MyComponent(props) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useReducer((p, n) => ({ ...p, ...n }), {
    name: '',
    surname: ''
  });

  // will use `useEffect` as an example with an API call
  React.useEffect(() => {
    SomeAPICall().then((data) => {
      setState({ 
        ...state, 
        name: data.name
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Similarly, you need to take the old state and update it with new values, then pass it to `setState`.

---

The `spread syntax` copies properties of an existing object onto a new object. Here's some reference if you're not familiar with this approach:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: This is the way hooks work, so you always need to take the old state and merge it with the new/next state.

Comment: What is the difference in your two examples?

Comment: The end result is the same, but I was just showing two different ways that you can use to accomplish the same thing. `React.useState` is probably easier to understand, so I would just stick with that for now, then move to `React.useReducer` if you have some more complex logic to handle.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a function which will accept all of your parameters and uses your defined `useState` methods.

This way you can customize and check for the value of the parameters too.

So it would be like below:

```
function Example() {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [surname, setSurname] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    function changeData({name, surname, email, password}){
        // call your setSates here
        setName(name)
        setName(surname)
        setName(email)
        setName(password)
    }

}
```

Notice that if you want to check the parameters to be passed you have to check them not to be `undefined`. If you don't check that it will set the variables to `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

you can use setData to update individual properties.

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
    name: '',
    surname: '',
    email: '',
    password: ''   
});

const setValue = (fieldName, value) => setData({...data, [fieldName]: value});

// to update name
setValue("name", "bob");
```

Comment: Thanks, do I have to use `setValue("name", "bob");`, can it be without `" "`?

Comment: you can't pass name without " ". if you pass without " ", it will find the name variable which is not defined.

Comment: So it will be `setValue("booleanCheck", "true");`?

Comment: No i meant first argument should be string, second can be any value.

Comment: What if there are more fields to be changed, not only name?

Comment: you can call setValue multiple times. or you can also call setData directly like `setData({...data, name:"test", age: 20 })`